# Python text based game: Invalid moves

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to coding and Python. I am struggling with why I am getting the keyError: 'item' when I am putting in a invalid direction. If I put any directions in that lead to another room I have no issues with the game and can complete it fully. I can grab every item and beat the boss. It is only when I put a Invalid move in that I error out from the start or after I have retrieved an item and try to put in a Invalid move. Any help will be very much appreciated. Here is the code I have so far:

```
def show_instructions():
    print()
print("Ghoul Text Adventure Game")
print("Collect 6 items to win the game, or be crushed by Blightcrusher, the Ghoul.")
print("Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West")
print("Add to Inventory: get 'item name'")

def main():  # Define the game
    pass

# Make dict for list of rooms you can travel, along with items you can pick up.
rooms = {
    'Cave Entrance': {'go South': 'Main Feast Area'},
    'Main Feast Area': {'item': 'Fleeting Soul Boots', 'go North': 'Cave Entrance', 'go West': 'The Deep', 'go South': 'The Spike'},
    'The Deep': {'item': 'Undead Leggings', 'go South': 'The Pottery', 'go East': 'Main Feast Arena'},
    'The Pottery': {'item': 'Shadow Helm','go North': 'The Deep', 'go East': 'The Spike'},
    'The Spike': {'item': 'Phantom chest', 'go North': 'Main Feast Area', 'go West': 'The Pottery', 'go East': 'Foggy Area'},
    'Foggy Area': {'item': 'Legendary Bow', 'go North': 'Graveyard', 'go West': 'The Spike'},
    'Graveyard': {'item': 'Phoenix Down', 'go North': 'SHADOW ROOM', 'go South': 'Foggy Area'},
    'SHADOW ROOM': {'item': 'Blightcrusher', 'go South': 'Graveyard'}
    }
# setting up format to show players current room and items in Inventory
def layout():
print('----------------------------')
print('You are in the {}'.format(current_room))
print('Inventory: ' + str(inventory))
if 'item' in rooms[current_room]:
    print('You see ' + rooms[current_room]['item'])
print('----------------------------')

# start player at Cave Entrance
current_room = 'Cave Entrance'
inventory = []
directions = ''


while True:
layout()
directions = input('\nWhat is your next move? ')  # prompting for directions
if directions in rooms[current_room]:  # Set so players move go with directions in rooms list
    directions = directions
    current_room = rooms[current_room][directions]
elif directions == str('get ' + rooms[current_room]['item']):
    if ['item'] not in inventory:
        print('You retrieved ', rooms[current_room]['item'])
        inventory.append(rooms[current_room]['item'])
        del rooms[current_room]['item']
else:
    print('Invalid')   # Make the rest of the moves invalid
if current_room == 'SHADOW ROOM':
    print('The boss, Blightcrusher Appears!')
    if len(inventory) == 6:
        print('You Crit Headshot Blightcrusher!')
        print('Blightcrusher shatters into pieces, You WIN!')
        print('Thanks for playing!')
    else:
        print('Oh no, Blightcrusher crushes you….GAME OVER!')
        print('Thanks for playing! Hope you enjoyed it!')
    break
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the 'Cave Entrance' has no item.
So, if you go e.g. North in that room, it passes the first if statement.
In the next one:

`elif directions == str('get ' + rooms[current_room]['item']):`

an item is required, because you are getting 'item' from the current room.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense thanks. Would it be the cause for this error as well when I go into a room, retrieve the item, and then put an invalid move? Like I go South into the room grab the item, go East grab that item. Then try to go East again, there is no room there and I am trying to have it say Invalid and instead I get this.                                                                 
    elif directions == str('get ' + rooms[current_room]['item']):
    KeyError: 'item'

Comment: As I understand you correctly, it won't as the item does not magically disappear from the list ;)

Comment: thank you! I will look into it more now with that in mind

Comment: You're welcome. You should tick the answer as correct and close the issue.

Comment: Another question, would it be best then to perform two separate loops? one for movement and then another for items?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Running two tasks separately at the same time required multithreading, which is not hard to do but totally unnecessary. One simple idea: in your dict you could add a new key called e.g. "itemPicketUp". There you would store if the item was already taken. In your loop, you then check if the command is "get ..." and !itemPickedUp. When initializing the rooms, you cloud add a dummy item in the Cave Entrance and also set "itemPickedUp" to True. After an Item is picked up, you also set this True in the specific room. I hope this helps you out.

Comment: I checked this as solved. Thank you for the advice. This has helped a lot! I really appreciate it.